# Why we can't see message counts for service bus topic in azure portal?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, messaging, azure-servicebus-topics

I want to see the count of active, dead letter, transfer dead letter messages at topic level currently. In Azure portal I can see these counts for service bus queue and subscription as below

[MessageCountDataInAzurePortal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oPMq.png)

But I can't see the topics related message count like this, instead we only have graph option but where we have to set the time range say last 12 hours.

[GraphToViewVariousMetricsForTopics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgT1r.png)

But I want to see the current active, dead letter, transfer dead letter count of a topic. Is it not possible to do so? Even in Service bus explorer I always see zero for these message count except for scheduled message count

[ServiceBusExplorerTopicInfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwtzT.png)

Comment: It is not possible to see messages at the topic level, as the entity itself doesn't store any of them but the subscriptions only. 
So you need to look at them at the subscription level and that is the only way, for topics